# Hibernate HQL NULL comparison pattern

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, hibernate

Imagine a simple web page allowing you to search Bookings like this:

[picture of web page http://locuslive.com/webdrive/booking.png](http://locuslive.com/webdrive/booking.png)

- If the Booking Number field is **not** populated I want to return all rows.
- If the Booking Number field **is** populated I only want to return that row.

I have been using a pattern in Hibernate (with an underlying MySQL database) to accomplish this that goes something like:

```
AND (:bookingNum IS NULL OR (:bookingNum IS NOT NULL AND :bookingNum = booking.bookingNumber))
```

I've recently been seeing some [weird performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549165/mysql-query-performance-huge-difference-in-time) and that got me wondering if there is a better pattern to use here. I'm sure non-Hibernate queries must have similar issues.

What do others do in this siutation?

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Hibernate criteria query, adding the predicate only if bookingNum isn't null.

Comment: I'm using HQL not Criteria. I can do similar using StringBuilder and IF statements. But I was hoping for something more elegant. Too hopeful?