# Finding Null IDs with HQL

Tags: hql

I'm constructing a hql query that needs to return orders where the User's ID is null:

```
        IList<Order> rows = DataContext.LoadList<Order>(
           "from Order " +
           "where OrderDate < ? " +
           "  and User.ID is null" //have also tried 'and User is null'
           , DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1));
```

This returns no records even though a direct query against the db returns a few dozen.

If I use the same query but replace the 'is null' with '33' (a valid userID), I'll get that user's orders. So the foundation of the query is valid - something's wrong with how I'm expressing the 'is null' bit.

Probably has something to do with the fact that, in the .NET project the Order object contains a complex User object where as in the database, the Orders table just holds integer (ID) that's a foreign key to the User table.

Still - since '***and User.ID = 33***' works as expected I don't follow why '***is null***' doesn't.

[This answer suggests I need to switch of the Criteria route.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262416/hibernate-hql-null-comparison-pattern) [This answer suggests that my current code should work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066492/hql-is-null-and-null-on-an-oracle-column)

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building a query statement, use a Query factory approach:

```
        Query q = new Query();            
        q.Criteria.Add(new Criteria("User.ID", CriteriaOperator.IsNull));
```

Works.